# Dexguard conflicting with other plugins in Android development

Tags: android, proguard, android-gradle-plugin, dexguard

I have been using Dexguard for my Android project, and it's been working fine until recently I had to use a another plugin. Because the way the other plugin is built, it is required that the project applies either "com.android.application" or "com.android.library". but since the dexguard plugin is an extension of the com.android.application which got replaced by dexguard, I can't use the other plugins that requires the "android" plugin.

```
//apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to get around this? I have contacted the authors of the plugin but it won't be practical to bother every plugin author for a solution.

---

Reference to my problem:

[Dexguard plugin specification](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issue-attachment/25/hvisser/android-apt/1415082484.34/25/gradle.png)

And here's the [plugin (android-apt)](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/src/3b04faf4d25d8df26a68a6464c0164d3d8f9bea1/src/main/groovy/com/neenbedankt/gradle/androidapt/AndroidAptPlugin.groovy?at=default) I'm trying to use that requires plugin: Android and only Android not dexguard.

Comment: Have you contacted Eric at DexGuard for an alternate option to Dexguard being a extension of "com.android.application"? I'm sure he suggests this way because it's simpler than have to hook all the Dexguard tasks in manually. If not then maybe it'll make the list for the next Dexguard release?

Comment: Thanks @scottyab, yes I have contacted Eric, he gave me a snippet of code to put in build.gradle, which I only just managed to get it working. so all good I will post the solution here soon. and yes he suggested keeping dexguard and manually apply other plugins which you would bypass the project configuration check that they normally have

Answer (score 0):

The latest DexGuard plugin (6.1.03) works alongside the Android plugin (1.0.0), instead of extending it. This should improve its compatibility with other third-party plugins.